# Java- a constructer that analyzes a string a converts it into an int

Tags: java, string, arraylist, int

How do you create a constructor that has a for loop that goes through or analyzes a string. then convert the string characters into integer then store it into an arraylist. for example if the number is "500" it should be 5 0 0 with each digit being the arraylist block.

Here is the code that i have so far;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BigInt {

    private String BigInt;

    private boolean pos;
    private boolean neg;

    private ArrayList<Integer> bigNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
    public BigInt(String b1){   
        b1 = "";
        for(Integer num : bigNum){      
        }
        //in a for loop if integer put into the array list
    }
    public  boolean sign(boolean a, boolean b){
        a = false;
        b = true;
        return false;
    }
    public String toString(){
        //check if boolean is + or - set that as the first character in the string
        //if( string - == first character)
        return BigInt;
    }
}
```

Comment: correction i mean to say store it into an array list.

Comment: Why are you setting `b1=""` what is the purpose of that?

Comment: I really think you need to put a bit more effort into the body of that loop.  This looks like the outline that your teacher gave you.

Comment: Feel encouraged to edit your question to include any corrections.  This way, we won't have to read the comments to get the full context of your question.

Comment: I made this outline so i can have some to work with instead of nothing. but for the for loop i dont know how to convert each string character and convert it to a int.

Comment: the b1 = "" is there because i thought i need an abstract string varaible that i can work into my for loop to convert the strings into an integer.

Comment: But isn't `b1` param the input parameter with the data you want to extract?

Comment: Code style: Don't name member variables the same name as the class.  Your class is named BigInt, and you have a static member in the class called BigInt.

Comment: How do you want to store a negative integer into your ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use / and % to break up large numbers.
Something like this

```
while (a > 10) {
    arrayList.insert(0, a % 10)
    a /= 10;
}
```

Comment: a is the original number that has already been converted to an integer, say 500

Comment: Please include that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
int num, index;
num = Integer.parseInt(b1);
index = 0;

while (num >= 0)
{
    arrayList.insert(index, num % 10);
    num = num / 10;
    index = index + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*How do you create a for loop that goes through or analyzes a string. then convert the string characters into integer*

```
    int x = Integer.valueOf(BigInt);
```

*then store it into an arraylist*

```
    for (int i = 0; i < BigInt.length(); i++)
    {
        BigNum.add(BigInt.charAt(i) - '0');
    }
```

Comment: I am so sorry for forgetting this but how do you implement this in my constructor. and thank you so much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: You literally copy that code into your constructor.  Perhaps you need to assign `BigInt = b1` as the first line.  I can't do your homework for you.